# Using Object in Pinia Store, how to validate it with vee-validate

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate, pinia

In my pinia store I have an object like so

`const quiz = ref({ title: “”, description: “”})`

I am referencing this object in a form with couple of inputs bound to v-model like

`<input type=“text” v-model=“quiz.title” />`

`<input type=“text” v-model=“quiz.description ” />`

I would like to validate the quiz object with vee-validate. But I can’t seem to find a correct example to do so. I have looked at this https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/examples/using-stores but it’s again not validation for object.

How do i validate with vee-validate while my v-model remains as-is (i.e quiz.xxx) . Sample code is available on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-udksgy?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: The referenced example from vee-validate has the typical validation logic moved to the store. There you can see the setup of the variables in the schema. If you stick to that setup, it should work.
There, the validation happens for the store member variables, not against an object type.

The other possibility is to do all the validation in your component, and save the values on change or on submit to the store.

Comment: @cwillinx - the example in the link definitely works...but i am not able to figure out how to define in store an object and link it to v-model....i have a pretty big object with 10s of fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after a bit of digging after @cwillinx comment.
I had to reference the error object in the form like so

`store.errors['quiz.title']`

instead of

`store.errors.title`